# Retain formatting in printf with %s

Tags: c, formatting, printf

So I have a string `char *str = someString();` and I want to print the string and retain any formatting that may be present in the string with `printf("%s", str);` So for instance, if `str` were equal to `"\033[32mPassed!\n\033[0m"`, I would want it to print `Passed!` in green followed by a new line. But currently, it prints the string literally.
Is this something `printf` can do or is it not designed for this? I understand that this could cause issues if the string contained something like `%d` without actually having a number passed.

Comment: Please add example code (it should be like 6 lines total, right?), and also a screenshot of the print-out you get.

Comment: The "formatting" is unrelated to `printf` and C, it's all done in the terminal. As long as you can pass the correct characters to the terminal, and it recognizes them as e.g. coloring codes, then it will work. So the big problem is, what *exactly* are you attempting to print? Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us.

Comment: ATSOTECK, "Is this something printf can do ..." --> No.

Comment: Note that `"\033[32mPassed!\n\033[0m"` employs [ANSI escape codes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sending `␛[32mPassed!␊␛[0m` to the terminal is what causes the desired effect.<sup>[1]</sup>

You are asking how convert the string `"\033[32mPassed!\n\033[0m"` into the string `␛[32mPassed!␊␛[0m`, just like the C compiler does when provided the C code (C string literal) `"\033[32mPassed!\n\033[0m"`.

`printf` does not provide a way to convert a C string literal into the string it would produce.

And nothing else in the standard library does either. The functionality of parsing C code is entirely located in the compiler, not in the executable it produces.

You will need to write your own parser. At the very least, you will need to do the following:

1. Remove the leading and trailing quotes.
2. Replace the four character sequence `\033` with character 0x1B.
3. Replace the two character sequence `\n` with character 0x0A.

---

Footnotes

1. Assuming the terminal understands these ANSI escape sequences.

Comment: Thanks for the help! Parsing the escape sequences was easier than I thought it would be.

Comment: Not really. Do you handle `\\033` correctly? What about `\b`?